# Jmeter SampleResult Memory Leak

Tags: java, jmeter, out-of-memory, performance-testing, hprof

I am using JMeter for performance testing and came upon a problem with OutOfMemory exception. I disabled the listeners and only configuring .jtl output as recommended on several pages. Still, the memory leak occurs. I've analyzed .hprof a little. Memory leak is caused by org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult class.

I suspect that jmeters stores all responses in RAM even though it does not need them for .jtl file. JTL is configured to write output as XML (it is needed because of TransactionControllers hierarchy of samples), but saving response bodies and headers is disabled. The whole final .jtl has about 60MB while the .hprof has more than 3GB.

Do you have any idea, what could cause this problem and if it is my suspection any idea how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try increasing the heap size for jmeter.

Comment: No, JMeter does not store all SampleResults in the memory. Must be an issue with your test, or the environment. But not enough information to help.

Answer (score 0):

[OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) exception can have many faces, i.e.:

- lack of Java Heap Space
- GC Overhead Limit Exceeded
- Requested array size exceeds VM limit
- Running out of swap
- etc.

So you need to carefully inspect *jmeter.log* file and/or .hprof file in order to get to the bottom of the issue and amend JMeter configuration to avoid it in the future.

Be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) it is recommended to use .csv output format, Transaction Controller structure should remain.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for a number of hints which can be applied to configure your JMeter instances for the maximum performance.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for articles. I need the xml format, because the .csv writes row only for the parent sample. And I need also the child samples. It could be done by unchecking "Generate parent sample" but that would cause mess in the samples with no way to match them together.